# Kurento MS OpenCV-Python

Tags: kurento

I need to apply OpenCV filter(face recognition) to the video stream. Is there any possibility to use python for this? Or it must be C/C++?

If it is possible to use openCV-python could you please point me to an example.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a specific filter?

A simple example (it goes from the start) is [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/face-detection-python-opencv) using python and opencv. It is for an image, but you can just loop it for every frame of the video, if you are not extremely concerned with performances and looking for something simple [here an explanation on how to extract frames from video with python and openCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/read-write-and-display-a-video-using-opencv-cpp-python/).

There are also several tutorial using neural networks (and python and OpenCV of course), like [this one for example](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/18/face-recognition-with-opencv-python-and-deep-learning/). These should have better results but they could be a bit more complicated and you may need CUDA (so a GPU) to run them..